# Hashing arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, hash

Is it possible to hash `lists`?

For example, I know that hashes of tuples are possible:

```
>>> hash((1,2,3,4,5,6))
-319527650
```

But is it possible to hash a `list`?

```
>>> hash([1,2,3,4,5,6])
hash_value
```

**Possible Solution:**

[Very in depth explanation to the hashing of lists, here.](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-March/037021.html)

Comment: Do you mean obtaining a hash value from an array, or do you mean some kind of array-like data structure which uses hashing internally?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Just try it:

```
>>> hash((1,2,3))
2528502973977326415
>>> hash([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> hash(frozenset((1,2,3)))
-7699079583225461316
>>> hash(set((1,2,3)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

So you can get `hash` of `tuple` and `frozenset` since the are immutable, and you can't do it for `list` and `set` because they are mutable.

Comment: Hashing of tuples however doesn't seem to work properly: `hash((1,2,3))` yields `2528502973977326415`, but `hash((1,2,4))` also yields `2528502973976161366` (tested on Python 2.7.9)

Comment: @cgogolin The values are different, everything works properly.

Comment: Oh dear, if I could, I would down vote my own comment. I fooled myself by only comparing the first few digits of the hashes.

Comment: @cgogolin good observation anyways. So many equal digits shouldn't be a coincidence, which indicates that the hashing algorithm is not very good.

Comment: "hashing algorithm is not very good".  Depends on what you need it for.  Are you using it for cryptography?  Well, don't do that, because the hashes are correlated with the input.  Do you need to obtain a hash value quickly for looking up dictionary keys?  Then this is a perfectly fine hash algorithm.

Comment: @cgogolin, that's why I always compare the first few and last few digits (hexits?) in an `md5sum`; not fool-proof, but it "feels" good.  I'll probably get burned one day...

Answer (score 39):

If you really need to use a list as a dictionary key, try converting it to a string first. 
`my_list = str(my_list)`

Comment: If you're going to go to the bother of converting to another data type, wouldn't a tuple make more sense?

Comment: For a list containing more lists a recursive conversion to a tuple is less trivial than a simpe `str()`.

Answer (score 10):

Python doesn't allow you to use mutable data as keys in dictionaries, because changes after insertion would make the object un-findable.  You can use tuples as keys.

Comment: That's slightly incorrect, a user-defined class can be written to be hashable (and therefore be able to be a key in a dict) but its pretty damn hard to create an immutable user-defined class in Python.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to convert it to a tuple:

```
print(hash(tuple([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])))
```