# Python : Merge two Pandas Dataframes on a column of list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, jupyter

I need to find intersection between two pandas dataframes based on a column of lists named "authors".[image]

But instead I get this error:

[image]

Comment: You need to show us what you tried. And as much as possible, paste the the code and errors here instead of providing screenshots. Make it easy for us to help you and you're likely to see more answers.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot merge on a list, because list cannot be hashed, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027199/hashing-arrays-in-python). One option would be to create an additional column by converting list to string and merge on it, e.g.:

```
df['authors_as_string'] = df['authors'].apply(lambda x: "-".join(x))
```

This would produce:

```
   id    authors authors_as_string
0   1  [a, b, c]          a-b-c
1   2  [a, b, c]          a-b-c
2   3     [a, b]            a-b
3   4     [a, c]            a-c
```

Then you can merge on that third column.

Alternatively you can try other solutions posted in that question.