# How to annotate function that takes a tuple of variable length? (variadic tuple type annotation)

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have a function that takes a tuple of different lengths as an argument:

```
from typing import Tuple


def process_tuple(t: Tuple[str]):
    # Do nasty tuple stuff

process_tuple(("a",))
process_tuple(("a", "b"))
process_tuple(("a", "b", "c"))
```

When I annotate function like mentioned above, I get these error messages

```
fool.py:9: error: Argument 1 to "process_tuple" has incompatible type "Tuple[str, str]"; expected "Tuple[str]"
fool.py:10: error: Argument 1 to "process_tuple" has incompatible type "Tuple[str, str, str]"; expected "Tuple[str]"
```

`process_tuple` really works with tuples and I use them as immutable lists of variable length. I haven't found any consensus on this topic on the internet, so I wonder how should I annotate this kind of input.

Comment: Do you get these errors when you run the code? I ran the code without any errors.

Comment: I get these errors when I run `mypy`.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

We can annotate variable-length homogeneous tuples using the `...` literal (aka `Ellipsis`) like this:

```py
def process_tuple(t: Tuple[str, ...]):
    ...
```

or for **Python3.9+**

```py
def process_tuple(t: tuple[str, ...]):
    ...
```

After that, the errors should go away.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple):

> To specify a variable-length tuple of homogeneous type, use literal
> ellipsis, e.g. `Tuple[int, ...]`. A plain `Tuple` is equivalent to
> `Tuple[Any, ...]`, and in turn to `tuple`.

Comment: This actually *is* a little bit counter-intuitive and counter-logical. If we assume that `List[str]` is okay for variable length lists, then why `Tuple[str]` is not okay for variable length tuple? And `(type(("a", "a")) == type(("a", "a", "a"))` yields `True`.

Comment: @Montreal: that's because `tuple`s and `list`s serve for different purposes: `tuple`s are heterogeneous containers (like positional arguments to an arbitrary function or a single table record from RDBMS, or in math world -- elements of cartesian product of different sets (or a union of cartesian products), so each coordinate may have a different type, but their number is usually fixed), while `list`s are homogeneous (like collection of same table records or a finite sequence of elements of some set)

Comment: @Montreal: so `Tuple[str]` is a single-`str`-object `tuple`, while `List[str]` is a collection of arbitrary number of `str` objects

Comment: Yes tuples and lists are usually used for different purposes but I think many Python programmers will learn about this convention only after a long time if at all. The reason is that the difference is not given by the language properties but rather by a habit which IMHO is not mentioned prominently enough in the documentation. --- I know only one place in the documentation: *Tuples ... usually contain a heterogeneous sequence of elements. ... Lists ... their elements are usually homogeneous.* https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: I understand your point, @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong, but despite the Zen of Python claiming "_There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it_", this is rarely **enforced** to be the case, and so much of _Pythonic_ Python is just by learning the way things **should** be.  I would also say that this `tuple` vs `list` usage goes far beyond Python.  So it is a good best practice to learn in coding more generally.

Comment: I would like to note that the best practice relates to the main difference between list/tuple, which is that they differ in mutability. So if one has a collection that may need to be extended best practice is to use a list, independent of the type of elements. Considering the usage outside of python, I'd note that a shopping list collects elements of different types [a liter of milk, a block of paper, a pen]. Another use are tuples in mathematics, which are not heterogenous https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple.

Comment: Concerning the difference in type spec:  Lists are mutable, so there is hardly a need for a type-spec with a fixed number of elements. Therefore the typing module treats them differently.

Answer (score 14):

### Python 3.9+

Use `tuple`:

```py
def process_tuple(t: tuple[str, ...]):
    pass
```

Since Python 3.9, `typing.Tuple` is deprecated. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) for `typing.Tuple` states:

> *Deprecated since version 3.9*: [builtins.tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) now supports `[]`.

### Python 3.8 and earlier

If you are on Python 3.8 or earlier, you should still use `typing.Tuple`:

```py
from typing import Tuple

def process_tuple(t: Tuple[str, ...]):
    pass
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the Ellipsis answer as posted by Azat you could make it more explicit by using [`@typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) or [`typing.Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union)

```
from typing import Tuple


@overload
def process_tuple(t: Tuple[str]):
    # Do nasty tuple stuff

@overload
def process_tuple(t: Tuple[str, str]):
    ...
```

Or with the Union:

```
from typing import Tuple, Union


def process_tuple(t: Union[Tuple[str], Tuple[str, str], Tuple[str, str, str]]):
    # Do nasty tuple stuff
```

Comment: I knew about it, but my tuples can be very lengthy, so it is not an option. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: btw `overload`s should go before implementation