# How can I add type annotations to a variable length tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, python-typing

I am trying (as an exercise) to type Curio's source code, but I have stumbled on a problem with its variable length tuples in the yielding parts of the code.

Curio's traps yield to the kernel a tuple of a known length, but the traps yield different lengths of tuples than each other.

For example, the `curio.traps._read_wait(fileobj)` yields a 4-tuple of type `Tuple[int, int, int, str]` whereas `curio.traps._spawn(coro)` yields a 2 tuple of type `Tuple[int, Coroutine]`.

The similarity between all their yield types is that the first item is always an `int` but the rest have type `Any`.

In the kernel, when it runs the coroutine to the next yield point, it expects an `int` as the first item and `Any`s after that. I was expecting `Tuple[int, Any, ...]` to maaybe work, but it gives an error saying that the `...` was unexpected.

```py
from typing import Tuple, Any

# Test code
vltuple: Tuple[int, Any, ...] = (1, 2)
vltuple = (1, 2, 3)
vltuple = (1, 'a', 'b')
vltuple = (1, [], 4.5)
```

Here are the exact error messages:

> ____.py:4: error: Unexpected '...'
>
> ____.py:4: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[int]", variable has type "Tuple[int, Any, Any]")

Comment: According with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54747253/how-to-annotate-function-that-takes-a-tuple-of-variable-length-in-python) there can only be annotated _Arbitrary-length homogeneous tuples_ as you see in [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id49) you cannot find any other reference to _Arbitrary-length_. It should be some hack but i recommend you to strip into 2 variables

Comment: How would one do that? Sorry about this. I'm pretty inexperienced in typing things. EDIT: Ah, you mean by doing `key: int; args: tuple; key, *args = vltuple`.

Comment: The first value of the tuple which will always be an int save it in other variable

Comment: Thanks so much. By changing it to `key: int; args: list; key, *args = (1, "a", b"b")`, mypy doesn't complain. Have a good day :D

Comment: Post the solution and mark it as answered. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented:

> According with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54747253/how-to-annotate-function-that-takes-a-tuple-of-variable-length-in-python), there can only be annotated
>   *Arbitrary-length homogeneous tuples* as you see in [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id49) you cannot
>   find any other reference to *Arbitrary-length*. It should be some hack
>   but i recommend you to strip into 2 variables

i.e.

**Solution:**

```py
key: int
args: list

key, *args = (1, 2)
key, *args = (1, 2, 3)
key, *args = (1, 'a', 'b')
key, *args = (1, [], 4.5)
```

By using extended unpacking you type and assign a fixed amount of variables (in this case one, just *key*) and the extra elements are put into another variable that can be typed individually