# python mypy error with immutable list as tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples, immutability, mypy

I encounter a weird error while defining an *immutable list* type:

```
import sys
from re import split
from typing import Tuple, List, NewType

tokens = split("(\d+\.\d+)", sys.argv[1])

# this works perfectly
# Tokens = NewType("Tokens", List[str])
# print(Tokens(tokens))

# this doesn't work ...
Tokens = NewType("Tokens", Tuple[str])
print(Tokens(tuple(tokens)))
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
> mypy main.py
main.py:13: error: Argument 1 to "Tokens" has incompatible type "Tuple[Union[str, Any], ...]"; expected "Tuple[str]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why the error occurs

When you using `tuple()` to transform a list to tuple, `Python` or at least `Mypy` doesn't know the exact type of elements in the tuple. Thus the error occurs.
Using different approaches to transform the list to tuple leads to different Mypy error:

```
token_x = tuple(tokens)
token_y = tuple(i for i in tokens)
token_z = (*tokens, )
```

```
main.py:15: error: Argument 1 to "Tokens" has incompatible type "Tuple[Union[str, Any], ...]"; expected "Tuple[str]"
main.py:16: error: Argument 1 to "Tokens" has incompatible type "Tuple[Union[str, Any], ...]"; expected "Tuple[str]"
main.py:17: error: Argument 1 to "Tokens" has incompatible type "Tuple[Any, ...]"; expected "Tuple[str]"
```

#### Solution

```
import sys
from re import split
from typing import Tuple, List, NewType

tokens: List[str] = split("(\d+\.\d+)", sys.argv[1]) # explicit annotation on here is great but not necessary
token_x = tuple(tokens)
token_y = tuple(i for i in tokens)
token_z = (*tokens,)

# this works perfectly
# Tokens = NewType("Tokens", List[str])
# print(Tokens(tokens))

# this doesn't work ...
Tokens = NewType("Tokens", Tuple[str, ...]) # explicitly annotate with Tuple[str, ...]
Tokens = NewType("Tokens", Sequence[str]) # or using Sequence[str], which is recommended by Mypy offical document
print(Tokens(token_x))
print(Tokens(token_y))
print(Tokens(token_z))
```

#### Appendix

Related question: [How to annotate function that takes a tuple of variable length? (variadic tuple type annotation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54747253)

Meaning of `Tuple[str, ...]`: `str, ...` stands of all the elements in the tuple are `str`

Mypy offical Doc: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#tuple-types