# How to add an empty item in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have created a dictionary in python like this:

```
 dictionary = dict(zip(numpy.arange(5), numpy.arange(5)*10))
```

And I use the dictionary as follows:

```
 y = np.vectorize(lambda x: dictionary[x])
```

Now I want to add a special situation: if the input `x` is an empty array, output also an empty array. And I tried to add an empty array in the dictionary:

```
 dictionary[np.array([], dtype='int64')] = np.array([], dtype='int64')
```

But I got an error:

```
*** TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Why does it not work? How should I handle the empty array here?

Comment: You can't. A dict key can not be a mutable object. An empty list/array is a mutable object. It makes no sense for `x` to be an array (empty or not) when doing `dict[x]`. At most, `x` can be an empty tuple.

Comment: @f. c.  Please check this answer `https://stackoverflow.com/a/7027308/12420884`

Comment: I get `ValueError: cannot call `vectorize` on size 0 inputs unless `otypes` is set` if I attempt to just call `y([])`. It never gets to your function. If you pass in an array of numbers, your function will never get an empty array either.

Comment: Furthermore, this looks like a massive XY problem. I suspect that you need to explain what you are really trying to do. `np.vectorize` is almost never the right answer.

Comment: If your dictionary represents a mapping that can be represented as a function (as here), you are better off converting the function to a numpy pipeline than using `np.vectorize`.

Comment: @DeepSpace Then what could I do to add the exception in this situation?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well, I want the function works like this: if input is an empty numpy array, then output an empty array. If input 0, output 0. If input 1, output 10, and so on...

Comment: @f.c. Sure. Taking the example of your function, it's easy. Just output `x * 10`. That should cover all your corner cases. But why are you creating an `np.vectorize` object? How do you plan on using it? I'm asking because I strongly suspect you don't need it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your dicitonary:

```
In [21]: dd = dict(zip(numpy.arange(5), numpy.arange(5)*10))
In [22]: dd
Out[22]: {0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}
```

the keys are numbers.  The same thing can be produced without `numpy`:

```
In [23]: dict(zip(range(5), range(0,50,10)))
Out[23]: {0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}
```

Your `vectorize` array access:

```
In [29]: y = np.vectorize(lambda x: dd[x], otypes=[int])
In [30]: y([0,1,3])
Out[30]: array([ 0, 10, 30])
In [31]: y([])
Out[31]: array([], dtype=int64)
```

I added the `otypes` so that the `[]` works.

I don't see why you want to add an entry that has an array key.  None of the other keys are arrays.  And as you found out an array can't be a key.

```
dictionary[np.array([], dtype='int64')]
```

`vectorize` passes scalar values from the argument to your function.  It does not pass an array.  So there's no point to having an array, empty or not, as a key.

Whether `np.vectorize` is the best tool for using this dictionary is another question.  Usually it doesn't improve speed over iterative access.  Using a dictionary might the underlying problem, since it can only be accessed on key at a time.

===

Without the `otypes`, `vectorize` raises an error

```
ValueError: cannot call `vectorize` on size 0 inputs unless `otypes` is set
```

`vectorize` makes a trial call to the function to determine the return dtype.

===

Here's a more robust version of your `y`, one that won't choke on a missing key:

```
In [32]: y = np.vectorize(lambda x: dd.get(x,-100), otypes=[int])
In [33]: y([1,2,3,10])
Out[33]: array([  10,   20,   30, -100])
```