# Immutable hashable list with correct typings

Tags: python, mypy, hashable

I need to use sequence of items as dict key and to feat `List[...]` type. If I use `tuple`, than it does not feat to a `List[...]` type and I cannot use `Tuple[...]` type, because tuple length is not known.

Is there any class (maybe from a 3rd party package) to be like hashable frozen list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hashing arrays in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027199/hashing-arrays-in-python)

Comment: @YannickFunk, so I need to subclass `list` and provide `__hash__` method manually? Is there any package I could install for that, which could also freeze the list? Unfortunately `frozenlist` package does not provide hashing out of the box(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immutable equivalent to `List[T]` is `Tuple[T, ...]`.

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple):

> To specify a variable-length tuple of homogeneous type, use literal ellipsis, e.g. `Tuple[int, ...]`. A plain `Tuple` is equivalent to `Tuple[Any, ...]`, and in turn to `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that [`frozenlist`](https://github.com/aio-libs/frozenlist) package have needed functionality

```py
    def __hash__(self):
        if self._frozen:
            return hash(tuple(self))
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Cannot hash unfrozen list.")
```

But this code is not included in any release (1.0.0 and 1.0.0a0 for that moment). Check if the situation will be improved. Here is the [issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/frozenlist/issues/150) I created.